# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, struts

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now. I have a web based application using Struts2, spring and Hibernate. I use Spring to wire struts action and business and dao layer together.
    I am using JMeter to load test the application. The application works well when I simulate 1 user repeatedly sending a get request, there are no issues. But when I add a couple of more users, after a while I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:510)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
192.168.1.118:1521:BAADB

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 109 more
```

So, I assumed its a connection leak, but shouldnt I get the same error when I simulate a single user continuously sending request (the only difference will be, I will get the error a little later). I enabled Hibernate stats to check for number of open session before I execute any dao request. All the session are closed after a request is processed. I am using OpenSessionInViewFilter, so there a session per request.

Following are all the files
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
            /WEB-INF/application-action.xml
            /WEB-INF/newbeans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter> <!-- Get spring to keep the session open for the whole request, so Hibernates lazy loads work -->
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- - Loads the root application context of this web app at startup. - 
        The application context is then available via - WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext). -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            net.sf.navigator.menu.MenuContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring and Hibernate file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
               xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
               xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.118:1521:BAADB" />
        <property name="username" value="htwork" />
        <property name="password" value="*****" />
    </bean>         
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.SerialNumbers</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Bunos</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Tms</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Custodian</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.CMISConfEntry</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.HeloTrackCurrentBunoConf</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.RepairBean</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.TDIncorporation</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Miscellaneous</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Inspection</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.HTComponentHistory</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.Component</value>
                <value>com.tda.baa.dao.TransferRequest</value>
                <value>com.tda.baa.dao.UsersTable</value>
                <value>com.tda.baa.dao.UserRoles</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.EHRCurrentBunoConf</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.SRCCurrentBunoConf</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.ASRCurrentBunoConf</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.ASRSubCurrentBunoConf</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.ASRTree</value>
                <value>com.tda.ht.bean.PMICTree</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="componentDAO" class="com.tda.ht.dao.component.ComponentDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="componentBusiness" class="com.tda.ht.business.component.ComponentBusinessImpl">
        <property name="iCompDAO" ref="componentDAO"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Action method call for the request componentBusiness - this is managed by spring

```
public String displayHeader() {
    Component c = componentBusiness.getComponentByPartNumber(partNumber);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Business Layer

```
package com.tda.ht.business.component;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.tda.ht.bean.Component;
import com.tda.ht.dao.component.IComponentDAO;

public class ComponentBusinessImpl implements IComponentBusiness {
    private IComponentDAO iCompDAO;

    //service layer method, transactions handled by spring
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Component getComponentByPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return iCompDAO.getComponentByPartNumber(partNumber);
    }
}
```

DAO layer

```
public class ComponentDAOImpl implements IComponentDAO {

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger
                .getLogger(ComponentDAOImpl.class);

//dao method called from service layer

@Override
public Component getComponentByPartNumber(String partNumber) {
    String[] arguments = { partNumber };

    long open = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSessionOpenCount();
    long close = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSessionCloseCount();

        log.error("Open " + open + " Close " + close);
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        log.error(" SESSION IS " + s.hashCode());

        try {
            Query q = s.createQuery("Select entry from Component as entry where entry.partNumber = ?");

            q.setParameter(0, partNumber);
            List<Component> list = q.list();

            if (list.size() > 0)
                return list.get(0);

            return null;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            //s.close();
        }
    return null;
    }        
}
```

In the dao layer, I gather stats about open and close sessions, the difference is never more than 4 since I have simulated 4 user. Looks like all the sessions are being closed. When the request is processed. If I don't use spring and manage Hibernate on my own with my own SessionFactory, opening and closing sessions, everything works and there are no errors.
I am confused since I dont see any Sessions being leaked, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? It says that you are using Hibernate3 objects in your XML, but do you actually have Hibernate3 jar's? Also it would make for easier reading if you split up your code block and have a separate code block for each file.

Comment: stacktrace is the place where error is occurred, but you have incomplete stacktrace, so you have time and an effort to resolve this error yourself. BTW spring uses templates to support transactions with hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

The `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't meant to be used in production, in production you want to use a connection pool, the `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't a connection pool, I suggest using something like Tomcat JDBC or Commons DBCP as the connection pool.

Your `hibernate.c3p0` settings are useless, as you are configuring and injecting the datasource with Spring, so those properties are ignored.

Finally you DAO code (might be) flawed, you shouldn't catch and swallow the `Exception` as this might break proper tx-management.

A final, unrelated, tip your `Log4jConfigListener` should be configured before the `ContextLoaderListener` if you want Log4j to properly initialize. Although I doubt you need it as `log4j.xml` is on yuor classpath so probably Log4J will be already initiliazed.

Comment: Thank you. Replacing DriverManagerDataSource with a connection pool seems to have fixed the problem. Exception block in DAO layer was just for debugging purposes while I was struggling with the errors. I dont plan to have that once I am done. What threw me off was I could simulate one or two users with continuous request without any problems. Thanks again.